# Java Permutation Challenge is to Slow

Tags: java, recursion, runtime, permutation

I have been working on a permutation problem from GeeksforGeeks. Here is the link for the challenge: http://www.practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problem-page.php?pid=702

The challenge is to take an array of numbers and for every possible order of these numbers in groups of 2 or 3, check if the sum of the numbers is divisible by 3. At the end of the program print out the number of groups that are divisible by 3.

An example would be... 
int[] array = {1, 2, 3} should print out 8.

Below is the code I used for this challenge. The code works but it is to slow. The runtime needs to be below 1.272s so how can I make this code faster? Or save it from executing so many lines?

```
  public static void PG2(int[] array, int l, int r, Counter count){
        int newR = r - 1;
        int i;
       if(l == 2){
           String number = String.valueOf(array[0]);
           String number2 = String.valueOf(array[1]);
           number = number.concat(number2);
           int aNumber = Integer.parseInt(number);
           count.divBy3(aNumber);
       } else {
            int temp;
            int temp2;
            for(i = l; i < r; i++){
                temp = array[l];
                array[l] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp;
                PG2(array, l+1, r, count);
                temp2 = array[l];
                array[l] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp2;
            }
        }   
    }

    public static void PG3(int[] array, int l, int r, Counter count){
        int newR = r - 1;
        int i;
       if(l == 3){
           String number = String.valueOf(array[0]);
           String number2 = String.valueOf(array[1]);
           String number3 = String.valueOf(array[2]);
           number = number.concat(number2);
           number = number.concat(number3);
           int aNumber = Integer.parseInt(number);
           count.divBy3(aNumber);
       } else {
            int temp;
            int temp2;
            for(i = l; i < r; i++){
                temp = array[l];
                array[l] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp;
                PG3(array, l+1, r, count);
                temp2 = array[l];
                array[l] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp2;
            }
        }   
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String t = input.readLine();
        int T = Integer.parseInt(t);

        while(T > 0){
            String arrayS = input.readLine();
            int ArrayS = Integer.parseInt(arrayS);

            int[] newArray = new int[ArrayS];

            String arrayElements = input.readLine();
            String[] ArrayElements = arrayElements.trim().split("\\s+");
            for(int i = 0; i < ArrayS; i++){
                int num = Integer.parseInt(ArrayElements[i]);
                newArray[i] = num;
            }
            int total = 0;
            Counter count = new Counter();
            PG2(newArray, 0, ArrayS, count);
            PG3(newArray, 0, ArrayS, count);

            System.out.println(count.counter);
            T--;
        }
    }
```

Here is the counter class:

```
public class Counter {
    public int counter;

    public void divBy3(int number){
        int total = 0;
        while(number > 0){
            total += number % 10;
            number = number / 10;
        }

        if(total % 3 == 0){
            this.counter++;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: what code is taking 1.2 seconds?

Comment: Use Java 8 stream API if you can use expressions.
Refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is creating a lot of unnecessary objects.

First, the counter class isn't needed, you can easily just keep an int counter of the number of groups that match the requirement.

When calculating if a sum is divisible by 3 you don't need to go through the digits, simply check (for an int `n`): `if (n % 3 == 0) { ...`

You are creating Strings and then converting ints to Strings and back again unnecessarily. Simply read the ints from the command line into an int array and use that.

```
// a main method that reads in ints and then keeps them as such
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int t = in.nextInt();
while (t > 0) {
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = in.nextInt();
    }
    int count = countGroupsOfTwo(arr);
    count += countGroupsOfThree(arr);
    System.out.println(count);
    t--;
}
```

Finally, recursion is going to be slower than a simple for loop iteration. I don't personally think recursion makes the solution cleaner, either.

I threw together a quick naive solution with those suggestions and it only took about 1/2 a second to run.